# Background image won't show up in header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to follow along on Colt Steele's course and for some reason my background image will not show up. I've checked everything and I'm stuck. I tried writing in the style tag and inserting the background in html instead of creating a separate css file like he did and it did not work. So instead I tried to just make a separate css file which I'm more comfortable with so far. Please let me know what I can do. Thank you!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    #header {
        background-image: url("imgs/header.jpeg");
    }
</style>

    <title>Pattern</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Quarantine Pal</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section id="header" class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1 class="display-3">Blog</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Do Something</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Another Thing</a>
    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564667005686-cce951e72bd0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3150&q=80) !important;
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the inline `<style>` block in your HTML. This is probably overriding the style set in your stylesheet.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code, check the image if it is valid.https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/em6hp2s0/16/

Comment: Are you sure that there is an "header.jpeg" in imgs folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL needs to be a string i.e you need to add an apostrophe ( ' ) on each side of it ('https://images.unsplash...'):

```
#header {
    background-image:  url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564667005686-cce951e72bd0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3150&q=80') !important;
}
```